# The Output of this Program in gcc Compiler is Segmentation Fault(core dumped).What i am doing wrong?

Tags: c++, linked-list, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

**This is a Binary Search Tree Implementation and i want to Know what's wrong with it?**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};

class tree
{
    node *root;
public:
    tree()
    {
        root=NULL;
    }

void insert(node *root,int key)
{
    if(root==NULL)
    {
    root->data=key;
    root->left=NULL;
    root->right=NULL;
    }

    else if(key<root->data)
    {
        node *temp = new node;
        if(root->left==NULL)
        {
            root->left=temp;
            temp->left=NULL;
            temp->right=NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            insert(root->left,key);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        node *temp=new node;
        if(root->right==NULL)
        {
            root->right=temp;
            temp->left=NULL;
            temp->right=NULL;
        }
        else
        insert(root->right,key);
    }
}

void search(node *root,int key)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        cout<<"Tree is Empty";
    else if(root->data==key)
        cout<<"Match Found";
    else if(key<root->data)
        search(root->left,key);
    else
        search(root->right,key);
}

node* getHead()
{
    return root;
}
};

int main()
{
    tree a;
    a.insert(a.getHead(),5);
    a.insert(a.getHead(),3);
    a.insert(a.getHead(),9);
    a.insert(a.getHead(),11);
    a.insert(a.getHead(),7);
    a.search(a.getHead(),11);
    return 0;
}
```

Maybe my implementation access some memory which i haven't declared.I just created a function to insert a node and a search function which return if tree is empty of match is found.Correct me what i am doing wrong.The ouput in my g++ compiler is segmentation Fault(Core Dumped).

Comment: You did not allocate memory to `root` inside `insert`.

Comment: @0x499602D2     Thank you.But why it will not work when i do node *root=new node; in class where i declared root. and also why my tree is empty when i search for any element it's saying tree is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this part:

```
if(root==NULL)
{
    root->data=key;
    root->left=NULL;
    root->right=NULL;
}
```

You perform a test for root being NULL, then you proceed to access members of root, which will cause a segmentation fault.  So, in essence, the code is doing:

```
if(root==NULL)
{
    NULL->data=key;
    NULL->left=NULL;
    NULL->right=NULL;
}
```

As a final note, it is best practice to **not** pass a variable of the same name as a member variable into a function.  It makes the code very hard to read and debug.  So, change the variable "root" in 'insert' and 'search' to "checknode", or something like that.  It will be much easier to debug your code.

Comment: Doing so as you mentioned is resulting an error base operand of '->' is not a pointer. Meaning null is not a pointer.

Comment: That is the point.   If 'root == NULL' is true, then accessing the a member of 'root' is equivalent to trying to access members in NULL.  It was for illustrative purposes only.  It was not for you to change your code.

Comment: The first thing you should do to fix your code is to change the local variables in 'insert' and 'search' to not use the member variable name 'root'.  After that, your debugging will become easier.